# Integral over null set is zero but integral of Dirac delta function is 1

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We know integral of any function over a null set is zero.
But for Dirac delta function ($\delta=+\infty$ iff $x=0$ otherwise $\delta=0$)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta =\int_0^0\delta =1.
$$
Is it a contradiction?

Comment: The [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta) is not actually a function, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: No, the expression you wrote is not a Lebesgue or Riemann integral, and $\delta$ is not a function in the conventional sense. Look for distributions (generalized functions): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29

Comment: See this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395850/dirac-delta-or-dirac-delta-function

Comment: Thank you, Nate, Andres and Baby Dragon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can regard it as a measure, the Dirac measure, which gives mass $1$ to $\{0\}$ , and zero mass to other subsets of $\mathbb R$ which do not contain zero(let's say Borel sets). For a Borel set $A\subset \mathbb R$ define:

$$\mu (A)=\begin{cases}1,&0\in A\\0,&0\notin A\end{cases}$$
Therefore: $$\int _{-\infty }^\infty d\mu=\int_{\{0\}}1\cdot d\mu+\int_{\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}}d\mu=\mu(\{0\})+\mu(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})=1+0=1$$