# missing $j*\omega$ in integral

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, indefinite-integrals, dirac-delta

let us consider following integral

[image]

according to  property of delta function,we can write this intgeral as

$\int^{t=\infty}_{t=t_0} e^{-j*\omega*t}$

or  we can write as

$e^{-j*\omega*t}/(-\omega*t)$ from $t=t_0$ to $t=\infty$,if we  calculate it  we get

**$\frac{e^{-j*w*t_0}} {w*j}$**

but i did not understand why is not given in formula  denominator part?thanks in advance

Comment: I think there has been an abuse of the delta integral here..I think the answer should involve explaining why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-t_0)f(t)dt = f(t_0)$. Which would be nice to see :). So in around about why you have asked an interesting question! +1! But this is just my opinion.

Comment: thanks very much,yes in that case $f(t)=e^{-j*\omega*t}$ but,during that calculation this part confused me

Comment: Please don't use the asterisk for multiplication outside of programming languages. In mathematics, it stands for convolution, not multiplication.

Comment: i should use \cdot right

Comment: Yes, use `\cdot`, or just don't use a multiplication symbol at all. It is rarely needed.

Comment: @datodatuashvili I started to write an answer about your derivation but I could not provide a satisfactory (to my standards) explanation of the above identity. So I leave it to others to provide a better answer. But basically the delta function only picks out certain values of the function $f(t)$.

Comment: $\cdot$ ok thanks in advance

Comment: simple you can write dato,it is name,datuashvili  it is surname :)

Comment: I will bare that in mind Dato. Though auto complete fills that in for me ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395850/dirac-delta-or-dirac-delta-function).

In less technical language: The delta “function” has the defining property that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)f(x)\,dt=f(0)$$
for any continuous function $f$. Substituting in $x=t-t_0$ with $f(x)=e^{-j\omega x}$ immediately yields the desired result.

Your rewrite of the integral “according to property of delta function” is not according to any property of the delta known to me.

Comment: That was the answer I was going to put but is it out of the scope of this particular question to why this integral holds? I do not want to overload/monkey patch on another question if it is not necessary :).

Comment: @Chinny84 I was puzzled about your reluctance to post an answer. Not sure what you mean by “out of scope”. I would have liked to link to an answer that is more directed at the OP's level, but a quick search did not reveal such an answer. (Perhaps I gave up too easily.) … Oh, just saw your followup comment. As you say, never mind …

Comment: I think it was a miscommunication. I wasn't to sure if the answer needed to explain why the integral with the delta function holds. But having a look at the link you provided it seems it would be too technical. Don't  worry, I think I am just over analysing the question :). Great answer :).