# Integral definition of delta function and Kronecker symbol

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta, kronecker-symbol

I know the following two definitions for the delta function and Kronecker delta, respectively:

(1) $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iwt}}{2\pi}\mathrm{d}t = \delta(w)$

(2) $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{i(m-n)t}}{2\pi}\mathrm{d}t=\delta_{m,n}$

First question: What is the difference between the delta function and the Kronecker delta? Especially in view of eq. (1), couldn't I say (2) $=\delta(m-n)$? Or would this mean something different?

Second question: Why are the integration limits different? I would think that I could replace $w$ in (1) by $(m-n)$ to get to definition (2), but obviously this wouldn't work because of the different integration limits.

Comment: First, a good starting point on Dirac delta: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395850/dirac-delta-or-dirac-delta-function   Then, the Kronecker delta is such that it is equal to $1$ if $m=n$, while the Dirac delta $\delta(w)$ is in some sense $=\infty$ for $w=0$...this is due to the very definition of the Dirac delta as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dw f(w)\delta(w-w_0)=f(w_0)$. The integration limits in (2) need to be such that the integral yields $1$ if $m=n$ and zero otherwise...this does *not* work if you replace $-\pi$ and $\pi$ with $-\infty$ and $\infty$

Comment: In general, the Dirac delta works for *continuous* variables and is associated to integrals, while the Kronecker delta works for *discrete* variables and is associated to summations.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo I realize this doesn't work if I replace pi by infinity, the question was: why? The two definitions basically look completely alike except for the different limits of integration.

Answer (score 2):

You presented two formulas for Kronecker delta and Dirac delta, neither or which are really used as *definitions* of those concepts. In practical terms, a remedy for confusion is to read the actual definitions of [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and do some work with these things.

But yes, there is a relation here.

```
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|            |  Kronecker delta   |    Dirac delta    |
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Arguments  | Integers           | Real numbers      |
| Dual space | Circle             | Line              |
| Functions  | Periodic functions | L^2 functions     |
| Expansion  | Fourier series     | Fourier transform |
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

The duality referred to is [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality). It leads from integers to a circle (which we represent by $[-\pi,\pi]$), to periodic functions, to Fourier series. The same line of reasoning leads from real numbers to $L^2$ functions to Fourier transform.

The formulas you stated describe the Fourier series/transform of Kronecker/Dirac delta. Despite the many parallels between the series and transform, one does not get from one to another by mere formal manipulations. See, e.g.,  [Difference between Fourier series and Fourier transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221137)